# Elasticsearch: Multi-level nested query not working

Tags: java, json, search, elasticsearch

My mapping is as follows:

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "person": {
            "properties": {
                "lastUpdated": {
                    "type": "long"
                },
                "isDeleted": {
                    "type": "boolean"
                },
                "person": {
                    "properties": {
                        "car": {
                            "type": "nested",
                            "properties": {
                                "model": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "make": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "last_name": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "first_name": {
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have two documents:

```
{
    "person": {
        "first_name": "Bob",
        "last_name": "Doe",
        "car": [
            {
                "make": "Saturn",
                "model": "Imprezza"
            },
            {
                "make": "Honda",
                "model": "Accord"
            }
        ]
    },
    "isDeleted": false,
    "lastUpdated": 1433257051959
}
```

and

```
{
    "person": {
        "first_name": "Zach",
        "last_name": "Foobar",
        "car": [
            {
                "make": "Saturn",
                "model": "SL"
            },
            {
                "make": "Subaru",
                "model": "Imprezza"
            }
        ]
    },
    "isDeleted": false,
    "lastUpdated": 1433257051959
}
```

I wanted to query the `car.make` field and so, I wrote the following query:

```
{
    "query": {
        "nested": {
            "path": "person.person.car",
            "query": {
                "match": {
                    "car.make": "Saturn"
                }
            },
            "inner_hits": {}
        }
    }
}
```

However, I am not getting anything back results back in return. When I remove the `person` level object and try to search, then it works. Any idea how to go about doing multi-level nested queries?

---

EDIT: On the other hand, when I structure my data like this and query then it works.

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "person": {
            "properties": {
                "car": {
                    "type": "nested",
                    "properties": {
                        "model": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "make": {
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "last_name": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "first_name": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

{
    "first_name": "Zach",
    "last_name": "Foobar",
    "car": [
        {
            "make": "Saturn",
            "model": "SL"
        },
        {
            "make": "Subaru",
            "model": "Imprezza"
        }
    ]
}

{
    "first_name": "Bob",
    "last_name": "Doe",
    "car": [
        {
            "make": "Saturn",
            "model": "Imprezza"
        },
        {
            "make": "Honda",
            "model": "Accord"
        }
    ]
}

{
    "query": {
        "nested": {
            "path": "person.car",
            "query": {
                "match": {
                    "car.make": "Honda"
                }
            },
            "inner_hits": {}
        }
    }
}
```

This way the query works. I feel like this has something to do with multi-level nesting. Multi-level nesting is not working.

Answer (score 0):

The nested path attribute needs to be "person.car".

Add "type": "nested", above the (2nd level) person properties line if you wish person to be a nested field type, which is required for Nested Query searches. The default field type is object field.

The naming you are using is confusing, try to rename your mapping not to use person twice.

```
{
    "query": {
        "nested": {
            "path": "person.car",
            "query": {
                "match": {
                    "make": "Saturn"
                }
            },
            "inner_hits": {}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried that query and I get an error `QueryParsingException[[my_index] [nested] nested object under path [person] is not of nested type]`.

Comment: As in the answer: Add "type": "nested", above the (2nd level) person properties line if you wish person to be a nested field type. Edited answer to be more clear.

Comment: Ok, I recreated my index with the 2nd level person as nested. That query path should be `person.person` as following: http://pastebin.com/Nfj0gcTj. Your query results in an error because path "person" (1st level) is not nested. That query I put in pastebin works, but returns no results.

Comment: This is because your naming mucks with the ES understanding the query. If you rename one of your 'person' fields then it will function. If you rename the first level then keep the query the same, if you rename the second level person you need to change the "path" to whatever you rename it to.

Comment: Renamed it, still the same issue, empty results. The example I posted is bad due to that name, but I tried this same thing with different names multiple times and it's the same error. Could this be an issue with ES?

Comment: Which level did you rename and could you pastebin the query after renaming please? Edit: I've never had an issue with multi level nesting, although my mapping structure was never identical to yours

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81298/discussion-between-daniel-hoffmann-mitscherling-and-user1757703).